# The std::cout does not output anything

Tags: c++

I am working through Stroustrup's book, Programming Principles and Practice Using C++.  I am able to enter the temperatures but I do not get std::cout in the console.  I have no compile errors.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> // I added this which is different from the book

void push_back(std::vector<double> temps, double value) { // I added this which is different from the book, maybe I don't need this but I found it doing a search
    temps.push_back(value);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> temps;

    double temp = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double high_temp = 0;
    double low_temp = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter some integers"<< '\n';  // I added this in for the prompt

    while (std::cin >> temp)
        temps.push_back(temp);

    for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i) {
        if (temps[i] > high_temp) high_temp = temps[i];
        if (temps[i] < low_temp) low_temp = temps[i];
        sum += temps[i];
    }
        std::cout << "High temperature: " << high_temp << std::endl;  // There is no output for this and the next two lines
        std::cout << "Low temperature: " << low_temp << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Average temperature: " << sum/temps.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What console? How are you compiling, running, and viewing the output of this program?

Comment: You're almost certainly running the program within your IDE (development environment).   That creates a window, and output from your program is directed to that window.   Then, when the program terminates, the window is destroyed and disappears fast enough that you don't see output.    Either find a way to run you program in a window that won't be immediately destroyed, or add a statement at the end of `main()` that waits for additional input.

Comment: `void push_back(std::vector<double> temps, double value)` Your vector is passed by value so any changes made to it in the function are not visible outside the function because that object disappears when the function ends. Try `void push_back(std::vector<double>& temps, double value)` instead. Since you don't appear to be using that function it won't matter right now, but if you do in the future you should be aware of it.

Comment: And another thing - a loop like `while(std::cin >> temp)` will keep looping until you enter something that can't be a valid double (a letter, for example, or an EOF character (ctrl+z on windows)). Simply pressing enter on a new line is not enough.

Comment: How to you pass argument? In interactive mode, `std::cin >> temp` would block until you explicitly stop the input (`Ctrl+D` for some terminal) or close the terminal.

Comment: I am using CLion's console for monitoring the output.  I added the & as suggested by @Retired Ninja but that did not work either.  I will see if I can figure out how to run in a separate window.  By the way, I am just learning C++ so thanks for your help.  I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @jrok that was it.  It needed something to stop the loop.  Also, as suggested I could use the 'stop' function.  Thanks for the asistance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it keeps looping waiting for input.
I changed it a little to ask how many values to input in order for you to check that the output is actually working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> // I added this which is different from the book

void push_back(std::vector<double> temps, double value) { // I added this which is different from the book, maybe I don't need this but I found it doing a search
    temps.push_back(value);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> temps;

    double temp = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double high_temp = 0;
    double low_temp = 0;
    int ntemp;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of temperatures to input:";
    std::cin >> ntemp;

    std::cout << "Please enter " << ntemp << " doubles"<< '\n';  

    for (int i = 0; i < ntemp; ++i)
    { 
        std::cin >> temp;
        temps.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i) {
        if (temps[i] > high_temp) high_temp = temps[i];
        if (temps[i] < low_temp) low_temp = temps[i];
        sum += temps[i];
    }
        std::cout << "High temperature: " << high_temp << std::endl;  // There is no output for this and the next two lines
        std::cout << "Low temperature: " << low_temp << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Average temperature: " << sum/temps.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now that is a smart idea for directing the number of inputs.  Very cool.

Comment: do you see the output in the console this way? if so, the problem wasn't the std::cout statements ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't see anything in output because you the program terminates as soon as the instructions to execute finish.
You could use getch(); or system("pause");
In this way the program will require a keyboard command.

Comment: I will try that out also for future programs.

Answer (score 0):

[I tried your code online](http://cpp.sh/2s73b) and actually got the `std::cout`-prints in the console. However, as jrok and Jarod42 mentioned in the comments, the user has to terminate the while-loop by entering input that can't be parsed to a double. Revisit section `4.6.3 A numeric example` in Stroustrup's book (Programming Principles and Practice Using C++) again. There it says:

> We used the character '|' to terminate the input — anything
> that isn’t a double can be used. In §10.6 we discuss how to terminate input and
> how to deal with errors in input.